# LINQ group by creating multiple keys for the same DateTime

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I've got a nested LINQ group by query based off this [nested group example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545974.aspx) that is creating multiple keys for the same DateTime.

```
var queryNestedGroups =
    from lockAssignment in db.LockAssignment
    where lockAssignment.UserId == userIdForUsername
    group lockAssignment by lockAssignment.DateStart into lockAssignmentsByDateGroup
    from lockAssignmentsByZoneGroup in
        (from lockAssignment in lockAssignmentsByDateGroup
         group lockAssignment by lockAssignment.Lock.Zone.ZoneName)
    group lockAssignmentsByZoneGroup by lockAssignmentsByDateGroup.Key;

// Three nested foreach loops are required to iterate  
// over all elements of a grouped group. Hover the mouse  
// cursor over the iteration variables to see their actual type. 
foreach (var outerGroup in queryNestedGroups)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("outerGroup.Key = {0}", outerGroup.Key);
    foreach (var innerGroup in outerGroup)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("\tinnerGroup.Key: {0}", innerGroup.Key);
        foreach (var innerGroupElement in innerGroup)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("\t\tinnerGroupElement: {0}, innerGroupElement.DateStart: {1}", innerGroupElement, innerGroupElement.DateStart);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the console output:

```
outerGroup.Key = 03/11/2015 10:45:55
Jewelry:    innerGroup.Key: {0}
        innerGroupElement: System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.LockAssignment_F0A35C00917489FA2C4D63DCAECAAD7A1EC03543B62C35206BF0542C5EAF1D8A, innerGroupElement.DateStart: 03/11/2015 10:45:55
        innerGroupElement: System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.LockAssignment_F0A35C00917489FA2C4D63DCAECAAD7A1EC03543B62C35206BF0542C5EAF1D8A, innerGroupElement.DateStart: 03/11/2015 10:45:55
Watches:    innerGroup.Key: {0}
        innerGroupElement: System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.LockAssignment_F0A35C00917489FA2C4D63DCAECAAD7A1EC03543B62C35206BF0542C5EAF1D8A, innerGroupElement.DateStart: 03/11/2015 10:45:55
outerGroup.Key = 03/11/2015 10:45:55
Watches:    innerGroup.Key: {0}
        innerGroupElement: System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.LockAssignment_F0A35C00917489FA2C4D63DCAECAAD7A1EC03543B62C35206BF0542C5EAF1D8A, innerGroupElement.DateStart: 03/11/2015 10:45:55
        innerGroupElement: System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.LockAssignment_F0A35C00917489FA2C4D63DCAECAAD7A1EC03543B62C35206BF0542C5EAF1D8A, innerGroupElement.DateStart: 03/11/2015 10:45:55
```

I'd expect to see only one outerGroup.Key for `03/11/2015`, like so:

```
outerGroup.Key = 03/11/2015 10:45:55
Jewelry:    innerGroup.Key: {0}
        innerGroupElement: System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.LockAssignment_F0A35C00917489FA2C4D63DCAECAAD7A1EC03543B62C35206BF0542C5EAF1D8A, innerGroupElement.DateStart: 03/11/2015 10:45:55
        innerGroupElement: System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.LockAssignment_F0A35C00917489FA2C4D63DCAECAAD7A1EC03543B62C35206BF0542C5EAF1D8A, innerGroupElement.DateStart: 03/11/2015 10:45:55
Watches:    innerGroup.Key: {0}
        innerGroupElement: System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.LockAssignment_F0A35C00917489FA2C4D63DCAECAAD7A1EC03543B62C35206BF0542C5EAF1D8A, innerGroupElement.DateStart: 03/11/2015 10:45:55
        innerGroupElement: System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.LockAssignment_F0A35C00917489FA2C4D63DCAECAAD7A1EC03543B62C35206BF0542C5EAF1D8A, innerGroupElement.DateStart: 03/11/2015 10:45:55
        innerGroupElement: System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.LockAssignment_F0A35C00917489FA2C4D63DCAECAAD7A1EC03543B62C35206BF0542C5EAF1D8A, innerGroupElement.DateStart: 03/11/2015 10:45:55
```

Is there a way I can make the outerGroup.Key more including of similar date's?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You're code seems to be working fine. My guess is that the dates isn't exaclty alike.

Change you're top debugging row to the following to also print out milliseconds (that's a start). There might otherwise be something different that is making .NET to believe that the dates isn't the same.

```
Console.WriteLine("outerGroup.Key = {0} {0:fff}", outerGroup.Key);
```

You can alter your code to group by more specific properties of the DateTime object with the following code

```
group lockAssignment by new {
        lockAssignment.Group.Year,
        lockAssignment.Group.Month
    } into lockAssignmentsByDateGroup
```

Comment: yeah, I'm sure the DateTime's were unique by milliseconds... :D

Answer (score 1):

By using Kati's suggestion [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cb58ae5f-5db9-4054-92b6-a1bf63764574/group-by-date-but-ignoring-the-time-portion?forum=adodotnetentityframework) I was able to get the desired grouping I was going after as shown below:

```
outerGroup.Key = { year = 2015, month = 3, day = 11 }
Jewelry:    innerGroup.Key: {0}
        innerGroupElement: System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.LockAssignment_F0A35C00917489FA2C4D63DCAECAAD7A1EC03543B62C35206BF0542C5EAF1D8A, innerGroupElement.DateStart: 03/11/2015 10:45:55
        innerGroupElement: System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.LockAssignment_F0A35C00917489FA2C4D63DCAECAAD7A1EC03543B62C35206BF0542C5EAF1D8A, innerGroupElement.DateStart: 03/11/2015 10:45:55
Watches:    innerGroup.Key: {0}
        innerGroupElement: System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.LockAssignment_F0A35C00917489FA2C4D63DCAECAAD7A1EC03543B62C35206BF0542C5EAF1D8A, innerGroupElement.DateStart: 03/11/2015 10:45:55
        innerGroupElement: System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.LockAssignment_F0A35C00917489FA2C4D63DCAECAAD7A1EC03543B62C35206BF0542C5EAF1D8A, innerGroupElement.DateStart: 03/11/2015 10:45:55
        innerGroupElement: System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.LockAssignment_F0A35C00917489FA2C4D63DCAECAAD7A1EC03543B62C35206BF0542C5EAF1D8A, innerGroupElement.DateStart: 03/11/2015 10:45:55
```

Here's the updated query:

```
var queryNestedGroups =
    from lockAssignment in db.LockAssignment
    where lockAssignment.UserId == userIdForUsername
    let lockAssignmentStartDate = lockAssignment.DateStart
    group lockAssignment by new
    {
        year = lockAssignmentStartDate.Year,
        month = lockAssignmentStartDate.Month,
        day = lockAssignmentStartDate.Day
    } into lockAssignmentsByDateGroup
    from lockAssignmentsByZoneGroup in
        (from lockAssignment in lockAssignmentsByDateGroup
         group lockAssignment by lockAssignment.Lock.Zone.ZoneName)
    group lockAssignmentsByZoneGroup by lockAssignmentsByDateGroup.Key;
```